# Documenting an array of type T in vsdoc format for javascript, Did I Find a Bug?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, xml-comments, vsdoc

Following [these guidelines for vsdoc documentation](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2007/04/23/the-format-for-javascript-doc-comments.aspx), I've been unable to get intellisense to work properly for an array of a given type.  Here is some code that demos the problem

```
function MyType() {
    /// <summary>Class description here</summary>
    /// <field name="PropertyA" type="Boolean">Description of Property A</field>
    /// <field name="PropertyB" type="String">Description of Property B</field>
 }
MyType.prototype.PropertyA = false;
MyType.prototype.PropertyB = "";

function testFunc(arrayOfMyType) {
    /// <summary>Description of testFunc</summary>
    /// <param name="arrayOfMyType" type="Array" elementType="MyType">asdfasdf</param>

    // right here, I should get the intellisense for an item of type MyType but I don't
    arrayOfMyType[0].

}
```

Right after `arrayOfMyType[0]` I should get intellisense for MyType but I don't.  I've also tried a for-in loop to see if that would bring up the right intellisense but it doesn't.  I should note that `arrayOfMyType` does have proper intellisense for an `Array`, and if I change it from `Array` to `MyType` then I get the correct intellisense for that, but not as an `Array` of type `MyType` as commented in the example.

At the moment I only have access to pre-sp1 vs2010 so I'm not sure if its a bug they've patched or not.

Could anyone tell me if

- I'm writing my vsdoc xml comments incorrectly
- I'm correct or not about expecting to get the intellisense for MyType at that line
- The intellisense for the above snippet works in vs2010 sp1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh542725.aspx

```
function Point(x, y) {
    /// <summary>My class.</summary>

    /// <field name="x" type="Number">X coordinate</field>
    this.x = x;

    /// <field name="y" type="Number">Y coordinate</field>
    this.y = y;
}

function testFunc(arrayOfMyType) {
    /// <summary>Do a thing</summary>
    /// <param name="arrayOfMyType" type="Array" elementType="Point">Array of Points</param>

    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

VS ItelliSense does not support each and every feature of JS XML doc comments. I guess this is one of the unsupported ones.

Comment: thats too bad, i'll have to get on microsoft connect and suggest that as a feature / check for sure if its not implemented.  Its a shame too because I have some really awesome js intellisense stuff coming out that could be substantially cooler if this feature was implemented